# sort string arrays of texts by length python

Tags: python

I have an array that containts elements out of words. I want to have a sorted list at the end. How do I do this in python? Thanks

Eg:

```
SETACTION = "forever", "for one and",  "for two"
```

=>

```
SETACTION = "for one and", "for two", "forever"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a lambda that will sort first by reverse length then by length of the first element:

```
>>> sorted(SETACTION,key=lambda s:(-len(s), len(s.partition(' ')[0])))
['for one and', 'for two', 'forever']
```

Answer (score 1):

You can easily achieve that using `sorted` with a custom `key` and `reverse=True` like so:

```
>>> sorted(SETACTION, key=len, reverse=True)
['for one and', 'forever', 'for two']
```

Do keep in mind `forever` and `for<space>two` are the same length.

Comment: forever has the length of 1, for two the length of 2

Comment: Well then the accepted answer is incorrect. You're trying to sort by number of words.

Answer (score 1):

Just to go a little further: if you want strings of the same length to be sorted alphabetically, you can write a custom sorting function; for example:

```
SETACTION = "forever", "for one and",  "for two"

def my_sorting_func(x):
    return -len(x),x

# It will sort first by -length (thus by descending length) then by alphabetical order

print(sorted(SETACTION, key=my_sorting_func))
```